# GLSL - for loop not working

Tags: for-loop, opengl-es, glsl

I am playing with [GLSL Sandbox](http://glslsandbox.com/e#35131.0) somehow the `for` loop not working as I expected:

```
float map( vec3 p )
{
    p.yz = rotate(p.yz, mouse.y*10.);
    float aa = 0.;
    float b = box( p, vec3(1.,1.,1.) );

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    float off = float(i);
    vec3 q = p+off*.05;//<--pivot go down diagonally 
    float c = box( q, vec3(off,1.,1.) );//<--scale the box in x
    aa = min(c,b);
    }
    return aa;
}
```

I expect it to have at least 5 boxes gradually go down with the `xscale` become bigger. But the result seems like all the duplicated boxes end at the last result of the loop.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re never reading from `aa`, so it just ends up being the minimum of the last `c` and the original `b`. Rearranging things like this should work:

```
float b = box(p, vec3(1., 1., 1.));
float aa = b;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    …
    aa = min(c, aa);
}
```